# How to give a custom jquery function a done() result

Tags: jquery

i am trying to make function and give a 'done' result when done. 
This is the code i try to make work

```
$.fn.whatever = function( content, position ) {
   var oDeferred = $.Deferred(); 

   if(position == content.length)
   {        
      alert("DONE"); // I want the caller to see the function is done
      oDeferred .promise();
   }
   else
   {
      window.setTimeout('$("#' + this.attr("id") + '").whatever("' + content + '", ' + (position+1) + ');', 100);
   }

   return oDeferred;        
}
```

then call the function and check if it is done

```
$("#obj").whatever("enter some text here", 0).done(alert("PLOP"));
```

Hope someone can help me understand

Thanks in advance

Comment: Makes no sense without actually doing anything async, but you have to resolve the deferred?

Comment: I think you want [`oDeferred.resolve()`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.resolve/) where you have `oDeferred.promise()` (`oDeferred.promise()` [returns the underlying `promise` object](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.promise/), but you're not doing anything with that return value.)

Comment: Just rip apart one of the custom plugins and see how they've done it.

Comment: Why not just use a callback, you have to add an anonymous function to that done() call anyway, as what you have won't work, so why mess with deferreds when it has no benefit whatsoever ?

Comment: it's obvious i don't get it...
All i want is to wait till this function is over and call it again on another element

Answer (score 0):

Below is a function that will help you understand how you can use Deferred properly.

Here is a JS Fiddle you can use to see it working: http://jsfiddle.net/2SYtS/

Documentation for Deffered: http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/

```
var myFunction = function() {
   var deferred = $.Deferred();

    window.setTimeout(
      function() {
        // Do logic here
        var success = true;
        if( success ) {
          deferred.resolve();
        } else {
          deferred.reject();
        }
      }, 1000
    )

   return deferred.promise();        
}

$.when( myFunction() ).then(
  function() {
    alert("Success!");
  },    
  function() {
    alert("Failure!");
  }
);
```